# Can't add a wired connection though Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, wired

I don't see the option to add a wired connection on the Gnome network manager. Please see the screenshot. It used to have 3 rows but the top row is missing now. Do you know how to get the option back?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, it doesn't seem to have been answered.

With root, edit this file:

```bash
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change:

```bash
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

to:

```bash
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

[See here on Debian forums](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=416545)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think if you already have a wired connection established, it should show up on top, and then there would be an option to add another. Do you have a connection established already? If so, the default is for the OS to start it at boot time. I think Linux looks for network hardware at boot and auto-configures it to start at boot (for hardware it recognizes).

Comment: I set up using `ip` command:```